# Bind to a property in a ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datacontext

I have a `Templates.xaml` file in my project which contains the `ResourceDictionary` of styles.

I want to bind `Direction` of a `DropShadowEffect` to `MyNamespace.MyPage.LightDirection`. Currently I did this:

```cs
// MyPage.xaml.cs
/// <summary>
/// Direction of light source for shadows and gradients.
/// </summary>
public static double LightDirection => 45;
```

```xml
<!--Templates.xaml-->
<Style x:Key="ControlButtons" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Effect">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="4" Direction="{Binding LightDirection}" Color="Black" Opacity="0.5" BlurRadius="4" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <!--Other Setters-->
</Style>
```

```xml
<!--MyPage.xaml-->
<Page x:Name="MyPage"
      DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MyPage}">
      <!--MyPage as some other default attributes which I didn't write here-->
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="MyButton" Style="{StaticResource ControlButtons}">
            My Button
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

It works. The shadow direction is set to `LightDirection` and program runs normally. However, while debugging, debugger shows a binding error:

> Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element.

What is my mistake? How should I prevent this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest making a constant

```cs
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class Constants
    {
        public static double LightDirection { get; set; }
    }
}
```

XAML

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"                
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace">
    <Style x:Key="ControlButtons" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Effect">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="4"
                                  Direction="{x:Static local:Constants.LightDirection}"
                                  Color="Black"
                                  Opacity="0.5" 
                                  BlurRadius="4" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Or declare constant directly in XAML

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"                
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
                    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" >
    <sys:Double x:Key="LightDirection">45.0</sys:Double>
    <Style x:Key="ControlButtons" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Effect">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="4"
                                  Direction="{StaticResource LightDirection}"
                                  Color="Black"
                                  Opacity="0.5" 
                                  BlurRadius="4" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: It works and error is gone. However I used `LightDirection` in some parts of C# code also.

Comment: Where do you import your dictionary?

Comment: I used Blend to add this dictionary. It added `<ResourceDictionary Source="Templates.xaml" />` to `App.xaml`.

Comment: That being said, You can access dictionary key from C# code: `var lightDirection = Application.Current.Resources["LightDirection"]`

Comment: If you use MVVM However above approach is not good. If you want more clean code You can duplicate this data both in C# and XAML

Comment: I defined some constants and properties in `MyPage.xaml.cs` to generate some UI elements. I prefer all of them to be defined in a single place (MyPage class). Isn't there any way to bind from resource dictionary to C# code?

Comment: Well, you can define a class named `Constants`, declare properties as public static. And set properties in resource dictionary via `{x:Static yournamespace:Constants.LightDirection}`.

Comment: This worked! The `LightDirection` was static already, so I added `xmlns:MNS ="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"` and used `Direction="{x:Static MNS:MyPage.LightDirection}"`. Please include this solution in your answer so I can mark it as accepted solution.

Comment: Answer updated.